# Probability and Cartesian Plane!

Tags: probability, geometry

**Question:**
[(screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5ffU.jpg)

> An injured ant named "Pipee" has got stuck at point $P\left(\frac{2}{5}, \frac{3}{5}\right)$ inside a square $A B C D$ of the Cartesian Plane where the coordinates of $A, B, C$ and $D$ are respectively $(0,0),(2,0),(2,2)$ and $(0,2)$. Pipee can only move from left to right. If the line which goes through the point $P$ and another point inside $A B C D$ denoted by $Q$ has the slope not more than $\frac{3}{4}$, only then Pipee can escape. Rafin wants to save Pipee. If he randomly chooses the point $Q$ inside $A B C D$, the probability that Pipee can get free can be written as $\frac{r}{s}$ where $r$ and $s$ are coprimes. $r+s=?$

**My Approach:**
My idea was finding the area of the parts dissected by the line whose slope is $0.75$. Then the probability. Alas! It went wrong.

Here's the question link
https://gonitzoggo.com/archive/problem/425/english

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. – For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Thanks, actually i didn't have much time to write as i had some work.. i would change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save the Pipee line PQ should have slope not greater than $3/4$. Line going through P and having slope $3/4$ is line $a$ with equation $y=3/5 + 3/4 \cdot (x - 2/5) = 3/4 \cdot x + 3/10$. For PQ to have slope not greater than $3/4$ point Q should lie right to P and lower than $a$ or left to P and higher than $a$. Drawing these zones and finding their area we can get that possible area for Q point is $(3/5+9/5)/2 \cdot 8/5 +$ $(17/10 + 7/5)/2 \cdot 2/5 = 127/50$. Total area of square ABCD is 4, so probability is $127/(50\cdot 4)=127/200$. Then $r+s=327$.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, lets find the eqn of line with slope 3/4 and starting at P.

The equation would be, y = $\frac{3}{4}$x + c, solving with P as a point in this line, the final equation is 20y - 15x - 6 = 0

Now,let's find the intersection between this line and the line joining line joining (2,0) and (2,2) (as we are moving right).
Substituting for x=2 in the equation we get, y=$\frac{9}{5}$.

So for Pipee to cross the y must be 0<y<$\frac{9}{5}$ and we know $\frac{2}{5}$<x<2.

Probability of random number in range of y: $\frac{9}{5}$*$\frac{1}{2}$ = $\frac{9}{10}$

Probability of random number in range of x: $\frac{8}{5}$*$\frac{1}{2}$ = $\frac{8}{10}$

so, $\frac{r}{s}$ = $\frac{9}{10}$*$\frac{8}{10}$ = $\frac{18}{25}$

r+s = 43